# Is there a way to find beginner-friendly questions?

Tags: discussion, support

I understand the reason that there shouldn't be a specific stack overflow site for beginners and that it is normal to ask simple questions here.

I am trying to learn from the questions posted on stack overflow, but since I'm a beginner many of these are hard for me to understand, and finding a question that is beginner-friendly is very hard. I tried to search for a [beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beginner) but couldn't find one. I want to find questions tagged [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) but are also beginner-friendly. Is there a way to do that? Is there an equivalent to the beginner tag?

Comment: Consider go to tutorial site instead if you want to learn about the language, it's easy to learn from there (this is a humble recommendation). SO is not a tutorial site in the first place. You may also search specific term, instead of randomly trying to find beginner question.

Comment: I have learned the language, but I want to see problems/solutions and projects in ruby.

Comment: I see, then maybe you can browse through "famous" questions by votes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby?sort=votes. I don't claim that questions with high score are beginner-friendly, but it tends to be like that, since many beginners find them useful (but mind the date those questions were posted, SO won't accept questions like that anymore since they are not fit in now)